# Why does closing a scanner seem to break new scanners?

Tags: java, input, io, user-input

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.getNextToken();
        foo.getNextToken();
    }

    public void getNextToken() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
                //s.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above code, it works as you might expect. 
Every time I insert a line, the computer pastes the next line.

[image]

However, if I uncomment out the s.close() line, and run again, I get the following behavior:

[image]

For some reason, the hasNext() method continuously returns false despite the fact that there is very obviously a next argument. I tried a lot of things and I can't find any workaround. for example if I change the code to just

```java
public void getNextToken() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        s.close();
        return;
    }
```

Then, again, it works for the 1st statement, but then instantly gives a NoSuchElementException. 
Of course, if you don't close the 1st scanner, it works fine.

I don't see why closing 1 scanner should affect the other, but I've heard that it's bad practice not to close scanners, and more importantly, there's an annoying yellow error message if I don't. Can anyone tell me of a way to fix this, and why it happens? I could pass in the scanner as an argument in the main method and also close it there but that just seems a bit messy.

Comment: Because you closed `System.in`. Don't do that. Don't close the scanner. Don't create new ones either. Just keep using the same one. It will still work. Using multiple scanners on the same underlying input really *is* bad practice. You will lose data.

Comment: Thank you, can you add that as an answer?

Comment: What is the purpose of your while (true) loop? s.nextLine() should block waiting for input.

Comment: It doesn't in this scenario, tradeJmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you closed `System.in`. Don't do that. Don't close the scanner. Don't create new ones either. Just keep using the same one. It will still work.

Using multiple scanners on the same underlying input really *is* bad practice. You will lose data.